# Creating an SPF record for SMTP

Tags: spf

I send emails with 'smtp.orangehome.co.uk' set as my outgoing mail server.

I have set this spf record up for my domain - 
v=spf1 a mx ip4:(MY.WEBHOST.IP.HERE) mx:(MY-DOMAIN-HERE) a:smtp.orangehome.co.uk ~all

But a contact's email server is bouncing my email with this message: 
"550 The sender did not meet Sender Policy Framework rules. Please see http://spf.pobox.com. Your email looks like potential SPAM and has now been quarantined. If your email is urgent then you should contact the recipient by some other means."

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: What is the Return-Path domain used for your emails?  Does it match the domain where you've set up the SPF record?  Also, providing your actual domain information tends to be helpful when debugging these sorts of problems.

Comment: It may be that orange/ee's outgoing SMTP servers does not match any of your listed ip-addresses. If you have access to another mail-address where you can send a mail to, you can try to inspect the headers on the received mail to see which servers orange/ee is sending from.

Answer (score 1):

Send an email to check-auth@verifier.port25.com and you will receive an auto-response with diagnostic information.